# All downloaded files open twice when clicked from Chrome browser bottom ribbon

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have a strange problem for the last few months: Whenever I download a file and click on the file icon on the convenient chrome ribbon at the bottom of screen  (which automatically opens after any downloads) which shows the recently downloaded file the files seem to all open TWICE.

Not sure what is causing this.

This is agnostic to file type: i.e. For pdf's or Excel files etc. they open twice.

If it matters, this is on Win 10.

Anyone knows how to fix this or even any debugging steps?

Comment: Have you reset all Chrome settings yet? I suggest syncing everything to a Google account beforehand.

Comment: @NatsuKage Thanks! How do I check whether everything is synched? I believe I am signed in.

Comment: Also, how do I reset all Chrome settings? Where's the button for this?

Comment: To reset everything: Press the Three Dots on the top right and select Settings in the drop down menu. Then in the settings page, select Advanced on the left. Next select Reset and Clean Up. Then Restore Settings to their original defaults.  Be sure to save any passwords or bookmarks using sync beforehand!

Comment: @NatsuKage Thanks!  It does say "Sync is On". So I suppose it should be safe to reset everything.

Comment: Yes, it should. Be sure you know your Sync credentials....just saying. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, probably you double click to try opening the download. I think chrome switched to single click a while ago.

Comment: Amazing! Such a simple fix! This was bugging me to no end last few months. So silly that I never thought of trying the single click out myself!